# how to apply Linear gradient in Node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm still new in D3.js, here some question that need help.
May I ask about how to apply Linear gradient in Node?
I had tried a few time of changes, but its not work.

```
  // draw nodes
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(force.nodes())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")

     .style("fill", function(d) { 
     return color(d.group); })

      .style("opacity", options.opacity)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)

      .on("mouseout", mouseout)
      .on("click", click)
      .call(drag);


    node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d){return nodeSize(d);})
      .style("stroke", "#fff")
      .style("opacity", options.opacity)
      .style("stroke-width", "1.5px");

//Linear Gradient
node.append("stop")
.attr("offset","0%)
.style("stop-color","white");


node.append("stop")
.attr("offset","100%")
.style("style-color",function(d){return color(d.group);});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is going to help...but for linearGradient you need to define `defs` element and `linearGradient` element. To which you need to append the `stop` element.
I was able to replicate the gradient after looking into this article : https://www.visualcinnamon.com/2016/05/smooth-color-legend-d3-svg-gradient.html

colors is an Array.

```
<defs :class="[`${cssPrefix}__gradient`]">
   <linearGradient :class="[`${cssPrefix}__gradient--group`]">
    <stop
       :class="[`${cssPrefix}__gradient--color`]"
       v-for="(c, i) in graphProps.colors" :key="`color-gradient-${i}`" />
     </linearGradient>
</defs>
```

```
const linearGradient = d3.select('defs linearGradient')
        .attr('x1', '0%')
        .attr('y1', '0%')
        .attr('x2', '100%')
        .attr('y2', '0%')
        .attr('spreadMethod', 'pad');

    const col = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range(colors);

    linearGradient.selectAll('stop')
        .data(col.range())
        .attr('offset', (d:any, i:number) => { return i / (col.range().length - 1); })
        .attr('stop-color', (d:any) => d);
```

[image]